# With Paypal, is there a way to display how much has been donated to a specific donation button using their api?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm making something similar to kickstarter, where I'd like to track the progress of donations to a single project. I've seen their widgets, and it's not what I'm looking for.

Is there anything I can do to display the amount that's been donated thus far?

Answer (score 0):

No. This does not currently exist. The widgets are the only ones with this capability.
Perhaps you make something yourself with the TransactionSearch, GetTransactionDetails API's and a custom 'item_name'?